# cakephp shopping cart default admin password

Tags: php, cakephp

Thanks for reading my post. I planned to create online shopping cart website. so i plan to look at the cakephp shopping cart plugin(due to is awesome). but i like to know the default admin password for cakephp shopping cart tool. here is the link for the cakephp shopping cart 
[cakephp shopping cart](https://github.com/andraskende/cakephp-shopping-cart)

I know the username is admin and password -> ???.. I have tried may combination of password but nothing worked. it is sha1 decryption with a salt crypter if i am not wrong.

Even i google a lot to find the password. But nothing helped. Question are raised on that topic but seems unrepiled..here is the link

https://github.com/andraskende/cakephp-shopping-cart/issues/4

just like to know the password..to check it.. thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is hard to find the default password.. but can reset your password

find your security.salt value app\config\core.php

if suppose let it be "abc123" and you plan to set your password as "admin" then

do a sha1 encryption of value abc123admin You can online conversion for link

sha1 conversion

Then edit the output result in your database..

then try to login it will success

Comment: You could also simply try and log in and extract the password-hash from the sql log. This has the benefit of not needing to know anything about how the app has configured auth (like assuming/guessing it's a `sha1` hash).

Answer (score 0):

Andraskende told you the solution in that post:

```
INSERT INTO `users` VALUES ('4e800ecf-b5bc-4fc6-b78f-67884317134f', null, 'admin', '6cfb5e7ba5fa202e923f45c534b87344440591e9', '1', '2011-09-26 00:34:07', '2011-09-26 00:34:07');
```

Change this with the encripted value (md5 i guess) for example if you want the default pass was 'admin' then change `6cfb5e7ba5fa202e923f45c534b87344440591e9` with `21232f297a57a5a743894a0e4a801fc3`

Or change directly on your database of course :)

Comment: thanks for reply first.. i have changed the value 21232f297a57a5a743894a0e4a801fc3 directly in the database and tried to login with username = admin and password= admin but it doesnot help .. if i am wrong in steps correct me

Comment: If you check the sql log what shows?? Reading some code i think that it's not md5 encryption (i will edit answer later)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know this plugin but you can try to allow all action of your application adding temporarily this in your AppController:

```
$this->Auth->allow();
```

and then create a New User.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me. I just went into my products controller, replaced the index() function with:

```
public function index() {
echo AuthComponent::password('admin');
die;
}
```

Go to yourshopdomain.com/products and it will show a value.

Cut and paste that value into the admin password field for admin in your db. Then revert the index function back to what it was before.

I found this via an issue and answer by the original developer on github.

Of course, it would be dangerous to do this in a production environment so only do it if you are developing your app locally and remember to revert back to the original index function.

Answer (score 0):

I try below:

1. Change function UsersController.admin_add() => UsersController.add()
2. Change View/Users/admin_add.ctp => View/Users/add.ctp
3. Goto: http://localhost/cakephpshop/users/add
4. Create new admin account
5. Go to and login: http://localhost/cakephpshop/users/login

(*)Can change password direct from mysql user: admin/009bb9a65ad55d0e8c9d0d86dcb5bb61755b4612